# OData - shortening filter query with multiple conditions on same field

Tags: rest, odata

I am trying to perform a rather long OData filter to retrieve a collection of entities that fulfil multiple conditions.

As a straightforward solution, I am currently doing something like this:

```
$filter=(name eq 'A' or name eq 'B' or name eq 'C')  and (address eq 'addr1' or address eq 'addr2')
```

From the example, I am targeting 2 fields: 'name' and 'address'. For both of these fields, I am filtering by a (potentially very long) list of eligible values.

While the query presented already works, there's actually a limitation that lies in the character limit on the length of the entire API call (approx. ~8000 characters). If the use case expands, the query length will very likely exceed the character limit.

I have tried something like this to truncate the query a little:

```
$filter=(name eq 'A' or 'B' or 'C') ...
```

It doesn't work (syntax error), but I am wondering if there is a better way to structure the query so that the length can be shorter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for the `in` operator

```
$filter=name in ('A', 'B', 'C')
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/webapi/in-operator

Comment: perfect, thank you! 

i'll also add that the 'IN' operator is only supported from OData v4 onwards. unfortunately, i'm working with a OData v2 client, so I think I can only work with  what I have right now

Answer (score 0):

For those that find this page looking for **OData** queries for Azure Cognitive search, you would turn this:

```
$filter=(id eq '47415390' or id eq '106266659')
```

into this

```
$filter=search.in(id, '47415390,106266659', ',')
```

Notes

- Assumes id field is an Edm.String
- Make sure there are no spaces before or after your commas because it's considered part of the text you are searching for.
- Reference [this Microsoft Documentation on the subject](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/search/search-query-odata-search-in-function#performance-of-searchin).